# Bash shell scripting: how to detect Alt+N keystroke?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, shortcut-keys

I want to write a script that always listens in the background and executes a particular command when the user hits a specific key combination such as <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. How this can be done?

Comment: I see the `command-line` tag on this, but if you are using a gui or a terminal window inside a gui (now or some other time), check out AutoKey. It will allow you to easily define many hotkeys which can trigger anything from a simple text phrase substitution to the execution of an arbitrarily complex macro written in Python. It outputs keystrokes to the gui/terminal just as if you typed it. It also has a number of other features and is very powerful, yet easy to use. A fairly recent version is included in the Ubuntu repos. For info, see https://code.google.com/p/autokey/ . (migrating to GitHub)

Answer (score 7):

Download the following python module: [showkey.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sangmank/py-showkey/master/showkey.py)

Then create a python script (let's call it `test.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from showkey import ShowKey

def alt_n(arg):
    print "Alt N was pressed"

sk = ShowKey()
sk.addKeyAction([49, 56], alt_n)    # adds handler for Alt-N comb.
sk.run()
```

Put `showkey.py` in your PYTHONPATH or put both `test.py` and `showkey.py` in the same folder.

Run your python script this way:

```
sudo ./test.py
```

The `alt_n()` callback will be triggered when the user hits the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> combination. Adapt the handler content for your needs.

To know the keycodes (the same codes used by the [`showkey`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/showkey.1.html) command) to use with `showkey.py`, just run it as a script again with `sudo`.
All keypress events will be printed in your terminal.

```
$ sudo ./showkey.py 
Current terminal mode: OFF
Key pressed - keycode: 28
Key pressed - keycode: 56
[...]
```